# AHK Timing from 60 to 0

Tags: time, count, autohotkey

When I press (example) `f::` my time starts counting down from 60seconds to 0s. In the last two seconds I have to press `f::` and the countdown must start again from 60 to 0.

Is it possible through AHK to make me press with `f::` anytime within 60 sec and AHK to click within the last two seconds. I don't need it for a computer game and any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I haven't tried anything because either it doesn't exist, or I been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `f::`? Do you mean the keyboard key `f`, or something different?

Comment: Also, how would you like to handle clicking the key three times within those 60 seconds?